# Force Testflight Users to Update to New Build?

Tags: ios, testflight

Is it possible to force Testflight users to update to a new build? It would really simplify things to know that all users are on the same prerelease version.

As I understand it, when you "Finish Testing" a prerelease version, it prevents future installations of that version, but users who have already downloaded that version can continue to use it. Ideally I'd like to prevent any further use of the old build.

Answer (score 5):

The only real way is to have an api call in the beginning of the app that just checks the latest version and stops the user using the app until they update... this isn't going to help you much though because you've already released it prior to adding the api call

If your app makes other api calls though, maybe update the apis to require a version number in them and only function if the version number is equal to your most recent version?

If your app doesn't make api calls... I think you're out of options unfortunately

Comment: So sounds like Apple doesn't offer a solution. That sucks. I'll figure out my own workaround. Thanks for the tip.